# How to set an icon image in Menu bar on windows in .MAUI by Xaml?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, maui-windows

How can I add An Icon or an Image in menu bar in .MAUI by Xaml here :
[image]

Here what I tried ,in Appshell :

```
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp5.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp5"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
    IconImageSource="dotnet_bot.png"
    FlyoutIcon="dotnet_bot.png"
     
    />
```

In MainPage.xaml :

```
<MenuBar>
  <MenuItem Text="File">
    <MenuItem Text="Open" Icon="dotnet_bot.png" />
  
</MenuBar>
```

If My question not clear enough, you could ask for clarification and I will edit it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Shell.TitleView` to set the icon in the navigation bar. For example, the following XAML(**Appshell.xaml**) shows displaying an icon:

```
    <Shell.TitleView> 
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0"
                   Source="dotnet_bot.png" 
                   HeightRequest="50"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>
```

**Output:**

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [Display views in the navigation bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-7.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar).